# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I'm new to java oracle database coding and I'm getting this error when running the code below (eclipse kepler):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.32.166:1521:orcl", "username", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Error is for ojdbc14.jar:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at oracle.main.main(main.java:18)
```

While I tried to change ojdbc6.jar but a different error shows up:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at oracle.main.main(main.java:18)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:361)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
... 7 more
```

Reason I'm experimenting on the 2 jar is I'm not sure which is compatible to jdk 1.6 as this is were I'm gonna deploy (linux env) the executable jar once completed. Need help to identify what these errors are and ideas to fix them? thank you

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a database "called" orcl on the database server 10.0.32.166 with an oracle listener running on port 1521.

Do `lsnrctl status`from the console on server 10.0.32.166 and see if you have a line like `Service "ORCL" has X instance(s).` If you don't have that make sure the database is up and you have the correct SID and it is using the listener on port 1521.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to oracle. Where can i ran the lsnrctl?

Comment: If you mean using command prompt in windows. I'm getting a different error: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA using theline sqlplus username@10.0.32.166 then the password